# Uncrustify: Single Line Method Names & Remove spaces between double asterisk

Tags: objective-c, formatting, uncrustify

Two related questions here.

**1)** What setting do I need to use to make multiline method name a single line? For example, I have this:

```
- (NSArray *)nodesForXPath:(NSString *)xpath
                namespaces:(NSDictionary *)namespaces
                     error:(NSError **)error {
```

Which my current config turns into this:

```
- (NSArray*)nodesForXPath:(NSString*)xpath
namespaces:(NSDictionary*)namespaces
error:(NSError * *)error {
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
- (NSArray*)nodesForXPath:(NSString*)xpath namespaces:(NSDictionary*)namespaces error:(NSError * *)error {
```

---

**2)** How can I remove spaces between double asterisks in method declarations?

I can post my current config if that would be helpful.

Comment: I assume you've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903103/why-does-nserror-need-double-indirection-pointer-to-a-pointer And that's why you're asking. And I assume that your parsing on blanks and the space in between is messing you up?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/938775/643383) should help. Looks like

```
align_oc_decl_colon = true
```

should do the trick for your declarations, and

```
align_var_def_colon = true
```

will help your definitions. Read the linked question, though, as it mentions several other related settings.

Comment: In this case he wants to take the multiline definition and roll it back into a single line.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, add the following option:

```
sp_between_ptr_star = remove
```

To remove the space between the double asterisks.