# Objective-c Xcode method autocomplete style

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coding-style

I have always been wondering about that Xcode method styling. When you start writing some declared method it offers you autocompletion of whole method in one line like this:

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Is it possible to automatically arrange it like this:

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(timerRefresh)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];
```

Thanks.

Comment: As Alexander points out, make your own code snippet. I've created a dozen of my own snippets and my ability to knock out common code has gone through the roof. And you can format that snippet any way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could use [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) with the `align_oc_msg_colon_span` value set to `1`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938775/can-uncrustify-align-colons-in-objective-c-method-calls) for more informations.

If you want to make it more automatic, you might want to give [BBUncrustifyPlugin](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode) a try, and bind its "Uncrustify Active File" menu command to a keyboard shortcut.

The BBUncrustifyPlugin is available in [Alcatraz](http://mneorr.github.io/Alcatraz/) (along with a bunch of other very neat plugins), or you could install it by hand (but I'd recommend trying Alcatraz. Really :)).

This will not make it *totally* automatic (as "*re-indent as you type*" automatic) but this is pretty close in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [code snippet library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html).

Comment: I don't see how that's helping. Do you suggest adding a snippet for each and every method in Cocoa or am I missing something ?

Comment: Only for the ones you need to be multilined. I doubt that there is an alternative way to change internal behavior of autocomplete methods.