# Uncrustify ignore formatting new line at long objective c method decleration

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

I want uncrustify to ignore new lines which is formatted by developer but with my config file it does not do this.

What my code looks like and i want it unchanged

```
+ (void)doSometingAwesomeWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
                  howManyDaysLater:(BOOL)howManyDaysLater
                           myBroes:(NSMutableArray *)broes
                        completion:(AwesomeBlock)completionBlock
```

What uncrustify does when it formats

```
+ (void)doSometingAwesomeWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
    howManyDaysLater:(BOOL)howManyDaysLater
    myBroes:(NSMutableArray *)broes
    completion:(AwesomeBlock)completionBlock
```

I am using uncrustify 0.61 and my config file is http://www.megafileupload.com/edbM/uncrustify.cfg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest https://github.com/square/spacecommander.

Possible duplicate of [Can Uncrustify align colons in Objective-C method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938775/can-uncrustify-align-colons-in-objective-c-method-calls?rq=1)